# Lightning Component Quick Action Styling - remove gray background

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, lightning-quickaction

When we create a custom Lightning Component Action on the Case object, which uses the `force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader` interface, the background of the component is gray.

When we apply the `slds-theme_default` class to the top level `div`, we're able to make the background white on the inner elements, but there's still this gray outer element that we (seemingly) don't have a way to adjust it's CSS to make it white.

See the screenshot below (and also note the white background that's padded on the horizontal outer element):

[image]

Can this outer element's CSS be adjusted in this quick action context?  I'm just looking for a consistent look/feel like other standard quick actions.